# JQuery Taconite C# helper

Tags: c#, fluent-interface

I'm writing a helper class to wrap the functionality of [JQuery Taconite](http://malsup.com/jquery/taconite/#overview) plugin. The plugin enables you to process multiple DOM updates in a single Ajax call.

The class simply enables you to construct the appropriate xml structure that is sent back to the client. I'm trying to wrap this functionality in a fluent interface. The basic example looks like this:

```
FluentTaconite ft = new FluentTaconite(writer);
ft
   .Select("#id1").ReplaceContentWith("Hello World!").FadeIn("100")
   .Select("#id2").AppendWith("<div>Another div</div>")
return ft.Output();
```

What I'm worried about is this, what structure would you expect be created after a call to this:

```
ft.Select("#A").AppendWith("<div id=B/>").AppendWith("div id=C/>")
```

Is your expectation to build:

```
<div id=A>
   <div id=B>
      <div id=C/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div id=A>
   <div id=B/>
   <div id=C/>
</div>
```

The question is - are you expecting context to shift to a newly added content or remain at the selector?

**Update**
The project in question is uploaded to [code.google](http://code.google.com/p/sharptaconite/). Hope you find it useful.

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect it to remain at selector. Look at the following sample:

```
ft.Select("#A").Append("<div id=B/>").Select("#B").Append("div id=C/>").End().Append("<br/>");
```

I expect the following output:

```
<div id='A'>
    <div id='B'>
        <div id='C'/></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

AppendWith imo is too noisy, it's enough of simple Append. 'End' method has similar functionality to JQuery's one.
And I have one more question, are you sure that this will be more usable in comparison with javascript code?

Comment: I agree with removing With from the method names and I like the End functionality so I'll change internal id property to a stack. The class is used server side to simplify the construction of taconite response (ie user calls login method and server constructs various controls that are put in appropriate places when returned to client).